# How can I simultaneously apply multiple rotate transforms by toggling classes?

Tags: css

I'm trying to apply various transforms to a given element or set of elements by clicking buttons to toggle classes on and off. This works for most things, but not when I try to toggle on more than one rotate transform. Once an element has two separate rotate transform classes (rotateX, rotateZ), the transforms stop working as I expect.

Please see my example here: http://jsfiddle.net/XTVd7/9/

**CSS**

```
#box {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    transition: all 1s;
}

.flip {
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(360deg);
    -moz-transform: rotateX(360deg);
    -ms-transform: rotateX(360deg);
    -o-transform: rotateX(360deg);
}

.spin {
    -webkit-transform: rotateZ(360deg);
    -moz-transform: rotateZ(360deg);
    -ms-transform: rotateZ(360deg);
    -o-transform: rotateZ(360deg);
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$("#flipBtn").on("click", function() {
    $("#box").toggleClass("flip");
});

$("#spinBtn").on("click", function() {
    $("#box").toggleClass("spin");
});
```

I'd expect that I could flip or spin the box at any time by toggling either class on or off. This is not the case once both classes have been added to it.

Comment: I believe it's because they're both trying to animate the same CSS property (-webkit-transform), and so trying to "transition" from rotateX(360deg) to rotateZ(360deg), or vice versa, doesn't quite work. That said, check out this fiddle that has different values for each property, and appears to function: http://jsfiddle.net/cypY4/

Comment: Interesting. You're on to something, but you'll notice that the transforms will still get hung up if you flip once and then spin once. I've also updated my example as I meant to use 'all' instead of '-webkit-transform'.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to toggle multiple values for the same property, you have to manually construct the property text ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BedgD/3/)):

```
function createToggleFunction(element$) {
    var transforms = {
        flip: 'rotateX(120deg)',
        spin: 'rotateZ(180deg)',
    };

    var state = {};

    return function(transform) {
        state[transform] ^= true;
        var text = "";
        for(var key in transforms) {
            if(state[key]) text += transforms[key] + ' ';
        }
        element$.css('transform', text);
    };
}

var toggle = createToggleFunction($('#box'));

$("#flipBtn").on("click", function() {
    toggle('flip');
});

$("#spinBtn").on("click", function() {
    toggle('spin');
});
```

A simpler solution would be to have two nested elements to represent the "box", with one of the transformations applying to the outer one and one applying to the inner one:

(See [this edited version of jblasco's fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BedgD/))

```
#spinner {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    transition: all 1s;
}

#flipper {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    transition: all 1s;
    border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="spinner">
  <div id="flipper">
    a
  </div>
</div>
```

JQuery:

```
$("#flipBtn").on("click", function() {
    $("#flipper").toggleClass("flip");
});

$("#spinBtn").on("click", function() {
    $("#spinner").toggleClass("spin");
});
```

Comment: That is indeed a pretty simple solution, but it requires a new nested div for each transition I want to make. I'm going to be making various transitions, more than just these two. I want to be able to toggle the transitions on one element. I'd expect that this can be done, unless there are limitations to transforms such as rotateX/Y/Z.

Comment: @blackcadillax: As jblasco points out, you can't set two different values for the same CSS property on the same element. If you want that property value to be the concatenation of multiple different transforms, then you need to do that yourself in the script - you can't use CSS classes.

Comment: I understand my problem now. For whatever reason I was thinking that the separate rotate values for the transform property were unique. Knowing this I should be able to devise a proper solution. Thank you for your input.

Comment: [Here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BedgD/3/) demonstrating constructing a multi-part transform yourself.